# Sound for scenes where there is product placement

Tags: product, placement

Hi,

This might a question out of left field but I am looking for examples of interesting sound design for scenes where product placement exists. I have looked into the theory of subliminal messaging through the use of sound to sell a product and I am not entirely convinced that when we hear coke being open and poured that the viewer immediately rushes to the fridge to get a coke.

In car commercials, or even in films where the character is driving a popular car, I have heard that they manipulate the sound of the car to make it sound a little more powerful. Ie: The recent James Bond. Is this altering of the sound of the car to make Bonds car bigger than life a decision of the director or is it the car company (Jaguar or Maserati)that asks for this to make their product sound bigger and better than everything else around it?

It would be great if any of you sound folk have some other interesting examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I like this version better..

[youtube]R63Ybfk84rs[/youtube]

Comment: Thanks for this. I think both videos are really interesting. The original recordings in this one which sound very different and not nearly as crisp and clean as in the video sent by Shaun. I see value in both and can't wait to show them to my students. 

Answer (score 2):

Not so much an example of sub-liminal, but an example of careful control of representation through sound would be Audi's sound team:

[youtube]HNQam68x2l8[/youtube]